# unable to style text size in flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to style the field where i type in the address, I want to make my font size smaller. I have tried changing the fontsize through the various "textstyle" properties in "Inputdecoration" but had no luck. How do i achieve it?

There are also these yellow lines underscoring my text. Is it an error?

Please help me out :/ would really appreciate it~

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                mapController = controller;
              },
              initialCameraPosition: currentPosition,
              markers: marks,
            ),
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: PlacesAutocompleteField(
                  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDVxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                  hint: 'Search Places',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
                  inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) async {
                    placeName = value;
                    print(placeName);
                    List<Placemark> placemark =
                        await Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress(placeName);
                    print(placemark[0].position);
                    Set<Marker> markers =
                        await getMarkers(placemark[0].position);
                    updateUI(placemark[0].position, markers);
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(currentPosition));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

code for the PlacesAutocompleteField:

```
class PlacesAutocompleteField extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Creates a text field like widget.
  ///
  /// To remove the decoration entirely (including the extra padding introduced
  /// by the decoration to save space for the labels), set the [decoration] to
  /// null.
  const PlacesAutocompleteField({
    Key key,
    @required this.apiKey,
    this.style,
    this.controller,
    this.leading,
    this.hint = "Search",
    this.trailing,
    this.trailingOnTap,
    this.mode = Mode.fullscreen,
    this.offset,
    this.location,
    this.radius,
    this.language,
    this.sessionToken,
    this.types,
    this.components,
    this.strictbounds,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onError,
    this.inputDecoration = const InputDecoration(),
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// Controls the text being edited.
  ///
  /// If null, this widget will create its own [TextEditingController].
  final TextEditingController controller;

  /// Icon shown inside the field left to the text.
  final Icon leading;

  /// Icon shown inside the field right to the text.
  final Icon trailing;

  /// Callback when [trailing] is tapped on.
  final VoidCallback trailingOnTap;

  /// Text that is shown, when no input was done, yet.
  final String hint;

  final TextStyle style;

  /// Your Google Maps Places API Key.
  ///
  /// For this key the Places Web API needs to be activated. For further
  /// information on how to do this, see their official documentation below.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  /// * <https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete>
  final String apiKey;

  /// The decoration to show around the text field.
  ///
  /// By default, draws a horizontal line under the autocomplete field but can be
  /// configured to show an icon, label, hint text, and error text.
  ///
  /// Specify null to remove the decoration entirely (including the
  /// extra padding introduced by the decoration to save space for the labels).
  final InputDecoration inputDecoration;

  /// The position, in the input term, of the last character that the service
  /// uses to match predictions.
  ///
  /// For example, if the input is 'Google' and the
  /// offset is 3, the service will match on 'Goo'. The string determined by the
  /// offset is matched against the first word in the input term only. For
  /// example, if the input term is 'Google abc' and the offset is 3, the service
  /// will attempt to match against 'Goo abc'. If no offset is supplied, the
  /// service will use the whole term. The offset should generally be set to the
  /// position of the text caret.
  ///
  /// Source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
  final num offset;

  final Mode mode;

  final String language;

  final String sessionToken;

  final List<String> types;

  final List<Component> components;

  final Location location;

  final num radius;

  final bool strictbounds;

  /// Called when the text being edited changes.
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

  /// Callback when autocomplete has error.
  final ValueChanged<PlacesAutocompleteResponse> onError;

  @override
  _LocationAutocompleteFieldState createState() =>
      _LocationAutocompleteFieldState();
}

class _LocationAutocompleteFieldState extends State<PlacesAutocompleteField> {
  TextEditingController _controller;
  TextEditingController get _effectiveController =>
      widget.controller ?? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.controller == null) _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(PlacesAutocompleteField oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.controller == null && oldWidget.controller != null)
      _controller = TextEditingController.fromValue(oldWidget.controller.value);
    else if (widget.controller != null && oldWidget.controller == null)
      _controller = null;
  }

  Future<Prediction> _showAutocomplete() async => PlacesAutocomplete.show(
        context: context,
        apiKey: widget.apiKey,
        offset: widget.offset,
        onError: widget.onError,
        mode: widget.mode,
        hint: widget.hint,
        language: widget.language,
        sessionToken: widget.sessionToken,
        components: widget.components,
        location: widget.location,
        radius: widget.radius,
        types: widget.types,
        strictbounds: widget.strictbounds,
      );

  void _handleTap() async {
    Prediction p = await _showAutocomplete();

    if (p == null) return;

    setState(() {
      _effectiveController.text = p.description;
      if (widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged(p.description);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController controller = _effectiveController;

    var text = controller.text.isNotEmpty
        ? Text(
            controller.text,
            softWrap: true,
          )
        : Text(
            widget.hint ?? '',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
          );

    Widget child = Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        widget.leading ?? SizedBox(),
        SizedBox(
          width: 16.0,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: text,
        ),
        widget.trailing != null
            ? GestureDetector(
                onTap: widget.trailingOnTap,
                child: widget.trailingOnTap != null
                    ? widget.trailing
                    : Icon(
                        widget.trailing.icon,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
              )
            : SizedBox()
      ],
    );

    if (widget.inputDecoration != null) {
      child = InputDecorator(
        decoration: widget.inputDecoration,
        child: child,
      );
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: _handleTap,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being you are not providing any widget to your `Text` which has got material design, there are many ways to fix it, like you can provide `Material` or a basic `Scaffold`. The recommended way would be to use `Scaffold` as it can provide many basic functionalities too.

---

So you need to wrap your `Stack` in `Scaffold`

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(...)
)
```

**Update (for text size)** :

In the `build()` method of `PlacesAutocompleteField` class, replace yours with following

```
var text = controller.text.isNotEmpty
    ? Text(
  controller.text,
  softWrap: true,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
)
    : Text(
  widget.hint ?? '',
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 50),
);
```

Comment: okay I'm sorry, that only managed to make the font size to a default small size. I still can't customise the styling :/ https://imgur.com/a/Da7wkiR

Comment: sorry, I wanted to show you that the changes in my code did not reflect on my app :/ I have updated my text code. I am trying to get the text to be size 20.0

Comment: @KwokWenJian Please delete previous comments (they are no longer needed) and check the updated answer.

Comment: it worked. However, may i ask what does the inputdecoration actually does? why does none of the properties do anything, when the documents say: it shows the labels and other visual elements that surround the actual text editing widget. https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_google_places/latest/flutter_google_places/PlacesAutocompleteField-class.html

Comment: because if i were to have to edit the root file, it seems rather at odds with the idea of flutter, being able to hotload and see the changes.. which in this case, when i do it your way, I have to rebuild the whole app, even hot restart doesn't work

Comment: Actually `InputDecoration` is used for `TextField` or `TextFormField`, and you were using it with `Text`, so it failed to work.